# AMD/ATi driver boots with no Unity/GUI display 12.10

Tags: unity, 12.10, drivers, ati, proprietary

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.10 64" ready to play some steam games.

The install went fine I did all the updates etc, however I need to install the proprietary AMD drivers (ATi HD5750) for any decent performance, so I go to the software sources and tick the driver listed.

When I reboot I get my desktop picture and mouse but no Unity whatsoever, I can right click the desktop etc but I have no side launcher or top bar.

I've had to re-install totally twice now to try and fix it but still the same each time.

Any help will as always be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug. Kernel supplied with 12.10 install disc won't work with AMD driver.

You can probably run terminal Ctrl-Alt-T

- Remove and purge AMD driver. After restart you will work with Mesa driver.
  instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)
- Update ubuntu to the latest kernel. (Perhaps you already have latest version as you did updates)
- Install latest ATI driver downloaded from AMD website.
- (important -  this is where most people fail ) Before reboot do 
  sudo aticonfig --initial -f

Comment: I installed the AMD driver in my fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.10 following [this guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide), so there is no bug.